# Local Alert not being called Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to create an alarm clock that sends a push notification when the predefined time comes up. I created a custom alarm class that inherits from UILocalNotification, but the alert does not show up. 
Code:

```
class shabbosClockViewController: UIViewController
{
    //variables****************************************************
    var localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    var alarmArray: [alarmObject] = defaults.arrayForKey("alarmArray") as [alarmObject]


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var testAlarm = alarmObject(title: "test title", hour: 15, minutes: 36, day: 3)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(testAlarm)
    }


}

class alarmObject: UILocalNotification
{
    var dateComponents: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

    init(title: String, hour: Int, minutes: Int, day: Int)
    {
        super.init()
        var calander: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        calander.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        dateComponents.hour = hour
        dateComponents.minute = minutes
        dateComponents.weekday = day
        dateComponents.weekOfMonth = calander.weekOfMonthInDate(NSDate())
        dateComponents.month = calander.monthsInDate(NSDate())
        dateComponents.year = calander.yearsInDate(NSDate())
        dateComponents.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()


        self.fireDate = calander.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)!
        self.alertBody = title

        println("\(self.fireDate) \n\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.fireDate!))\n\(dateComponents.weekday) \n\(dateComponents.weekOfMonth)")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

The app doesn't crash or print any errors, but the notification doesn't pop up when it is supposed to. The println() prints the correct date and time.

Comment: You aren't asking for permission to send the notification.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that. I ask permission in the app delegate (let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)